# Where/how to find ortophotos

Tags: qgis, data, south-africa

I am very new to Geographic Information Systems. I have a very basic inquery; How do I get hold of the newest ortophoto of South Africa to use as a background map for my GPS data? I'm using QGIS but I guess it doesn't matter which platform/system you use..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, the IEQGIS Ireland QGIS user group blog describes how to access the ESRI satellite image basemap layer from ArcGIS REST Service, by using the python consol in QGIS. http://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/adding-esris-online-world-imagery-dataset-to-qgis/

These are also the same images as used in Bing Aerial.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenLayer Plugin to display Googles Satellite/Orthophotos.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded it and installed it under the "manage and install plugin" under menu but it still does not show under the "plugin" menu.

Comment: In the "Manage and install plugins" menu, is the box next to the OpenLayers plugin checked/enabled?

Comment: It's in `Web` in 2.4

Comment: @NathanW: You're right.